# How to Jump only once in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity. I want to learn how to make my player jump only once.

I tried to google the answer but could not understand how to add a jump command in my script.

I have added my code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Ridgidbody component nammed as rb
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float ForwardForce = 2000f;
    public float SidewayForce = 500f;
    public float UpwardForce = 47f;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update


    // Update is called once per frame
    // FixedUpdate is for using Physics
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, ForwardForce * Time.deltaTime);   //Adding forward force

        if ( Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(SidewayForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if ( Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-SidewayForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if( Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, UpwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way I can think of to only jump once is to use a flag indicating that you have already jumped/are in the process of jumping. You then reset this flag when the character has landed, or performed whatever action is necessary for allowing a second jump, if you have such an ability.

```
bool isJumping = false;
```

And then in your `FixedUpdate` method:

```
if( Input.GetKey("space") && !isJumping )
{
    rb.AddForce(0, UpwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    isJumping = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot but can you please provide me the code for how to jump again I actually meant to jump once at a time 
it would be very helpful

Comment: @Bhaskarpal I can't provide the exact code to jump again because you have to have to define when you want to be able to jump again, and then detect those conditions. The answer that was linked in the vote to close your question provides better info on how to do this. Basically when you know you can jump again you just set `isJumping = false;`